# Echo results from a grep search in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script which searches for authentication fails. For example if the given file contains the following row:

```
Mar 19 15:54:18 precise3 sshd[16516]: Failed password for lotte from 127.0.0.1 port 47384 ssh2
```

The shell script will find it and write the results in a separate file as:

```
date: date    username: username    client IP: ip-address
```

Now I have the script which finds the authentication fails, but how can I write the data from the fail into the file? The script itself is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if egrep "sshd\[[0-9]+\]: Failed password for \w+ from [0-9.]+ port [0-9]+ ssh2$" /var/log/auth.log
then
    echo "date: date    username: username    client IP: ip-address" > /root/failedauth
else
    echo "No failed authentications found."
fi
```

Comment: Not very sure what the problem is. What I see is you use `> /root/failedauth`, while it should be `>> /root/failedauth`. Otherwise, the file will be truncated every time.

Comment: Well basically I want to extract the date, username and ip-address from the authentication log and write them out in the file. But that only in the case, if the authentication fail exists in the log.

Comment: `man grep` and searching for similar questions on this site would help.

Comment: Why? What are you going to do next? The reason I ask it that if you want to *do* something as a result of failed password attempts, you may be better off looking at something like [SEC - simple event correlator](http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/) or [syslog-ng OSE](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/opensource-logging-system). Both offer to option to extract data from logs and trigger actions base on correlated events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```bash
awk '/Failed password/ {print "Date: "$1" "$2" "$3"\tUsername: "$9"\t\tClient IP: "$11 }' /var/log/auth.log >> /root/failedauth
```

The above will simply find all the failed auth attempts and log them in /root/failedauth - if you want an line to be echoed if there are no results, you could do something like:

```
failures=$(awk '/Failed password/ {print "Date: "$1" "$2" "$3"\tUsername: "$9"\t\tClient IP: "$11 }' /var/log/auth.log)
test -n "$failures" && echo "$failures" >> /root/failedauth || echo "No failed auths found"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, yout grep can return several results, so your script can't work, or just for the first result.

I think you must save grep's result in a file and process each line of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial with Awk.

```
awk '/sshd\[[0-9]+\]: Failed password for [-A-Za-z0-9_]+ from [0-9.]+ port [0-9]+ ssh2$/ {
    print "date: $1 $2 $3  user: $9  ip: $11" }' /var/log/auth.log >>/root/failedauth
```

If there are no failed authentications, the script will print nothing.  (The date of the `failedauth` file will still be updated, though.)